# If $h$ has positive derivative and $\varphi$ is continuous and positive. Where is increasing and decreasing $f$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

The problem goes specifically like this:

> If $h$ is differentiable and has positive derivative that pass through $(0,0),  $  and $\varphi$ is continuous and positive. If:
>   $$f(x)=h\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}} \varphi(t) dt\right).$$
>   Find the intervals where $f$ is decreasing and increasing, maxima and minima.

My try was this:

The derivative of $f$ is given by the chain rule:

$$f'(x)=h'\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}} \varphi(t) dt\right) \varphi\left(\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$
We need to analyze where is positive and negative. So I solved the inequalities:
$$\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}>0 \land \frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}<0$$
That gives: $(-\infty, -√2) \cup (√2, \infty)$  for the first case and $(-√2,√2)$ for the second one. Then (not sure of this part) $h'\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}} \varphi(t) dt\right)>0$ and $\varphi\left(\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)>0$ if $x\in(-\infty, -√2) \cup (√2, \infty).$  Also if both $h'$ and $\varphi$ are negative the product is positive, that's for $x\in(-√2,√2)$.

The case of the product being negative implies: $$x\in [(-\infty, -√2)\cup(√2, \infty)]\cap(-√2,√2) = [(-\infty,-√2)\cap(-√2,√2)]\cup[(√2,\infty)\cap(-√2,√2)]=\emptyset.$$
So the function is increasing in $(-\infty,-√2),(-√2,√2),(√2,\infty)$. So the function does not have maximum or minimum.
Not sure of this but what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, your approach looks fine. But the devil is in the details…

First of all, your derivative obtained via the Chain Rule doesn't look quite right. It should be
$$f'(x)=h'\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}}\varphi(t)\,dt\right)\cdot\varphi\left(\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\cdot(x^3-x).$$
You were missing the last part of the Chain Rule when applied to integrals with variable upper limit.

Second, for some reason you were solving inequalities with $\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}$ being either greater or less than zero, as if it's a factor in the derivative — but it isn't! You have $\varphi$ **OF** $\left(\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$, not multiplied by it.

And third, you don't need to think much about $h'(\cdots)$ and $\varphi(\cdots)$ being positive or negative — simply because both are given to be always positive. Therefore, $f'(x)$ has the same sign as $(x^3-x)$, and so the only inequalities you need to solve are $x^3-x>0$ and $x^3-x<0$.

Comment: Man. Trying to do it fast I totally forgot the derivative of $\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}$. Also I was assuming that $\varphi$ takes the sign of the argument, same for $h'$. Thank you so much. It was and easy problem disguised.

Comment: @Lui: You're welcome! If my answer helped you, maybe you could accept it and upvote it?